# Nested reactive form array issue (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular 7 app in which I am trying to add a reactive form which populates a group of controls under multiple category heading. The HTML side of this I am comfortable handling.

Most of it is working with the exception of the population of the "Sources" group. I have verified that the itemArray is populating properly. However, once it is merged into the final sourceForm, there are no values for the controls under Sources/controls. I'm sure there is something wrong with my logic or types in passing back the array, but after attempting to resolve it for days now, I can't determine where the problem is. The code is below. Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong here?

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {environment as env} from '../../environments/environment';
import {OARDataService} from '../oar-data.service';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';
import {scSource} from './scSource-model';
import {scSourceCategory} from './scSourceCategory-model';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-sc-client-sources',
    templateUrl: './sc-client-sources.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sc-client-sources.component.css']
})
export class ScClientSourcesComponent implements OnInit {

    sourceForm: FormGroup;
    source$: scSource[];
    cat$: scSourceCategory[];

    constructor(private _oardata: OARDataService, private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._oardata.getscCategories().subscribe(data => {
            this.cat$ = data;
            this.createForm(this.cat$);
            console.log(this.sourceForm);
        });
    }

    public createForm(cat$: any) {
        var catArray = [];

        for (var c = 0; c < cat$.length; c++) {
            var selectedCat = this.cat$[c].scSourceCategoryID

            //catArray.push(this.buildCategoryHeader(cat$[c]))
            catArray.push(this._fb.group({
                CategoryID: this.cat$[c].scSourceCategoryID,
                Category: this.cat$[c].scSourceCategoryName,
                Sources: this._fb.array([this.getSourcesForCategory(selectedCat)])
            }));

            this.sourceForm = this._fb.group(catArray);
        }
        return this.sourceForm;
    }

    buildSource(sourceInstance: any): FormGroup {

        return this._fb.group({
            sourceID: [sourceInstance.scClientSourceID],
            sourceName: [sourceInstance.scSourceName]
        });
    }

    getSourcesForCategory(selectedCat: number): FormGroup {

        var itemArray = [];

        this._oardata.getscSources(selectedCat).subscribe(data => {
            this.source$ = data;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.source$.length; i++) {
                itemArray.push(this.buildSource(this.source$[i]));
            }
        });
        console.log(itemArray);
        return this._fb.group(itemArray);
    }
}
```

The images represent the values I see in the console. The itemArray:

[The ItemArry values when not inserted into the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9uao.png)

Then The sourceForm values:

[The sourceForm Values. Notice the NULL value under Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pljbY.png)

Comment: I would recommend to indent your code properly, it's really hard to read, I already gave up :D Best would be to create a demo to play with :)

Comment: ... also this is not a [mcve] we have for example no idea what those http-requests return, so there is no way to diagnose the problem, we can just **guess** that it returns what you are trying to insert to your form...

Comment: I think I was clear in my text that the array by itself is populating fine. That should rule out any need to question the http:// requests. Also, the code is indented, I'm not sure why this would be hard to read.

Comment: Well I tried your code with static data, by guessing how your structure looks like, and it worked perfectly fine. So unless you are willing to provide a MCVE it's really hard to help. You might even solve your issue yourself when creating a demo on e.g StackBlitz.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it. When it runs for me, the Category level populates, and I see Sources with it, but I get an empty array for values. However, if I look at itemArray by itself it has all the values I would expect to see in the right structure. So the issue is with the nesting of the array into the main form. If I can't figure it out, I will setup an MCVE on StackBlitz as you suggest. I thought the issue might be an obvious type mismatch or something like that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here is my test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7qdhm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Agree, the stand alone version appears to work, yet mine doesn't. I've added two images to convey the values I see in the console. Hopefully that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Could you just fork the stackblitz and recreate the issue, help me help you ;) Those images sadly doesn't help anything.

Comment: Thanks. I spent some time on the StackBlitx, but it's too time consuming to recreate the exact function of the data pulls from my db, and even if I wanted to invest the time, the codebase would end up completely different and not necessarily solving my problem. I understand your position, you can't fix what you don't see as broken. I'll have to fight through it or possibly just abandon the use of reactive forms and hard code it. I don't want to do that, but the time I am investing on something that should be a simple fix is frustrating. Thanks again for your help though....